# How to open several independent Safari 6?

Tags: safari, osx-mountain-lion

Is it possible to open several independent Safari 6 on Mountain Lion 10.8 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Terminal, and run this command

```
open -n /Applications/Safari.app/
```

This will open a new instance instead of a new window from the same instance.

Answer (score 2):

Why?!

Yet: `open -n /Applications/Safari.app/` from `Terminal.app`